# How to print tagged values from a file?

Tags: java, tagging

I had to write a code to identify the language of tweets and to print out the tweets of a certain language. I have written the language identification part, but cannot get to print only the lines necessary.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

public class Lang_Detect 
{
    public static weka.classifiers.Classifier c;
    public static HashMap<String,String> trigram=new HashMap<String,String>();

    public static void initiate() throws Exception
    {
        c = loadModel("C:\\Users\\DIV\\ff\\Maithili\\nb.model"); // loads nb model
    }
    public static NaiveBayes loadModel(String path) throws Exception 
    {
        NaiveBayes classifier;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        classifier = (NaiveBayes) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return classifier;
    }
    public static void read_trigram()
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\DIV\\ff\\Maithili\\Trigram.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                String words[]=line.split(":");
                trigram.put(words[0].trim(), "");
            }
            fis.close();
        }catch(IOException f){}    
    }
    public static String feature_vector(String line)
    {
        String vector="";

        String words[]=line.split(" ");
        HashMap<String,String> local_word=new HashMap<String,String>();

        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
        {
            char ch[]=words[i].toCharArray();
            for(int j=0;j<ch.length-2;j++)
            {
                local_word.put(ch[j]+""+ch[j+1]+""+ch[j+2], "");    
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : trigram.entrySet()) 
        {
            if(local_word.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            {
                vector+="1,";
            }
            else
            {
                vector+="0,";
            }
        }

        return vector;
    }
    public static String lang_tag(String file) throws Exception
    {

        String tagged_sentence="";
        int l=0,cntr=0;;
        //String words[]=sentence.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        StringBuffer str=new StringBuffer();

        read_trigram();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count=1;
        str.append("@relation Language\n");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : trigram.entrySet()) 
        {
            str.append("@attribute Trigram"+count+" numeric\n");
            count++;
        }
        str.append("@attribute class {HN,NP,MT}\n");
        str.append("@DATA\n");

        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                str.append(feature_vector(line)+"?\n");
            }
            fis.close();
        }catch(IOException f){}   

        Global.file_update("C:\\Users\\DIV\\ff\\Maithili\\HN_NP_MT_Unlabelled.arff", str.toString());

        Instances unlabeled = new Instances(
                new BufferedReader(
                  new FileReader("HN_NP_MT_Unlabelled.arff")));

        // set class attribute
        unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);

        Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);

        // label instances
        for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) 
        {
          double clsLabel = c.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
          String tag="";

          if(clsLabel==0.0)
              tag="HN";
          else if(clsLabel==1.0)
              tag="NP";
          else if(clsLabel==2.0)
          {
              tag="MT";
              Global.file_append("C:\\Users\\DIV\\ff\\Maithili\\Detected_Maithili_Tweets.txt", tag);
          }

          System.out.println(tag);

        }
        return tagged_sentence.trim();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        initiate();
        lang_tag("C:\\Users\\DIV\\ff\\Maithili\\tweets.txt");

    }

}
```

As you can see in the lang_tag(), I want to print the lines which are tagged as MT, But I cannot get the lines in any particular variable.
Can someone help me?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What is a sample input and corresponding output expected? What is the current behavior?

Comment: the input is a text file containing tweets of 3 different languages. I need the tweets of only 1 of those languages. The program is executing correctly (~90% F-Measure using Naive Bayes). I just am not able to figure out how to write the correct tweets in a new file

Comment: Looks like you are using a `file_append` method from `Global` and writing `tag` in it. Since `tag="MT";` in case `clsLabel==2.0`, you must be getting "MT" in the file isn't it? Or you are getting some kind of error?

Comment: yes I'm getting MT, i want to get the corresponding tweet as well as MT in the file

Comment: You don't have a `Global.file_append()` for tweet, you need to add that along with the `tag`. Which variable has the corresponding tweet?

Comment: no you dont understand, i have another class Global which has the method file_append.Since I'm creating an arff file I don't seem to know how to store the tweets in a particular variable

Comment: You must be reading the tweet somewhere in the code to determine the `tag` for it. At that point you need to store it to a variable and corresponding tag value. Then you can write it to the file.